# how to insert values from one table to another table in mysql with other parameters in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

This is My Code...

```
public bool InsertItemsToInventory(String PoNo,String rqy,String exPdate,String mfDdate)
        {
            bool status = false;

            if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            MySqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            newCmd.Connection = conn;
            newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           // newCmd.CommandText = @"Insert into inventory(ItemNu,ItemName,BatchNo,Category,Qty,Unit,Supplier,ExpDate,MfdDate,ID,Location) Values('" + ItemNo + "','" + ItemName + "','" + BatchNo + "'," + cat + "," + qty + "," + unit + "," + supplier + ",'" + exPdate + "','" + mfDdate + "'," + id + "," + 17 + ")";
            newCmd.CommandText = @"insert into inventory(ItemNu,ItemName,BatchNo,Category,Unit,Supplier,ID,Qty,Location,ExpDate,MfdDate) values ( 
                                        (select i.Number,i.ItemName,po.perchaseorderId,i.CatId,i.UniId,i.SupId,r.ID
                                        from porder po, request r,items i,supplier s, itemcategory ic
                                        where po.PrNumber = r.PrNumbr and r.ItemNu = i.Number and s.SID=r.sup and ic.CID = r.cat and po.perchaseorderID = '" + PoNo + "' ),'" + rqy + "','"+ exPdate +"','"+ mfDdate +"',' Inventory ')";
            newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            status = true;

            return status;

        }
```

Comment: Hey @Anushka, welcome to S.O. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please add more details to your question. You may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Thanx @dbugger ... Actually i want to add one table to another table and i pass some values as parameters int my form but i don't know how to write that query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
newCmd.CommandText = @"insert into inventory(ItemNu,ItemName,BatchNo,Category,Unit,Supplier,ID,Qty,Location,ExpDate,MfdDate) select i.Number,i.ItemName,po.perchaseorderId,i.CatId,i.UniId,i.SupId,r.ID,'" + rqy + "','"+ exPdate +"','"+ mfDdate +"',' Inventory '
from porder po, request r,items i,supplier s, itemcategory ic
where po.PrNumber = r.PrNumbr and r.ItemNu = i.Number and s.SID=r.sup and ic.CID = r.cat and po.perchaseorderID = '" + PoNo + "'";
```